# Will this Windows 8 version have Office on it?

Tags: windows-8

I've heard some people say that Windows 8 tablets will come with a free copy of Office, some people say that you have to buy Office, and some say that only if you get a "Windows RT" tablet it comes with Office.

Which is correct?

Comment: (as for the downvote, I wrote this post for http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5426/lets-get-started-with-windows-8?cb=1)

Comment: IMO, Wondering if Windows 8 will come with Office is not a problem that needs an answer from us. :)   Plus you jump from "Will it come with office?" to "What's RT?.

Comment: you're asking 2 questions in one, please ask one

Comment: updated to only ask about Office

Answer (score 2):

Office Home & Student 2013 RT Preview (possibly branded [without the "Preview"](http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-rt-office-and-certified-peripherals-information-uncovered)) will come bundled with Windows RT tablets for free. It will be upgradable to the final version of Office 2013 when it's released.

Comment: And, none of these devices will be available until late Oct.

Comment: "AFAWK" isn't very useful. It's just guessing at the future.

Comment: updated to only talk about office, and in addition removed the AFAWK :)